# Сноски, кавычки

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, сноски

Название сказки: **«Подушка убивает роженицу(2)».**
[(2) - надстрочный номер сноски.]

Текст сноски:
(2). Невестка убивает мать.

Имеется в виду, что с арабского допускается и другой перевод.
Вопрос следующий: номер сноски ставить внутри кавычек после последнего слова или вне кавычек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При оформлении сносок соблюдается следующая последовательность знаков:

4. Кавычки ставятся **перед** знаком сноски: **«текст»*.**
   [ * = цифра сноски]
   [**§160. Оформление сносок**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-13%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%C2%A7160)

**«Подушка убивает роженицу»*.**
[ * = 2 (маленькая цифра над кавычками)]